# Вопрос, как сделать альбом в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Мне нужно сделать альбом, там может быть около 6-10 фотографий, как мне сделать место хранилище в базе данных (на примере Mysql)
Неужели мне надо будет создавать 10 полей,чтобы в каждое поле занести запись.
То потом все таки мне придется перебирать через foreach (ибо этот альбом будет находится в под альбоме)
 Подскажите, как будет более грамотно.

Comment: На мой взгляд правильным было бы организовать что-то вроде структуры "фотография -> альбом" (есть таблица "photo" с album_id и таблица "album" c parent_id, если у вас вложенные альбомы). В таблице album какие-то общие сведения об альбоме, а в таблице photo ссылка на файл и ее название, например. Таким образом можно сделать неограниченную вложенность альбомов с неограниченным кол-вом фото в каждом.. как вариант

Answer (score 0):

я создавал в похожем случае просто столбец с названием photo и в него перечислял пути к фотографиям и разделял их звездочкой и в php есть функция которая разделяет строку по разделителю explode(),`$img = explode('*', $item['image']);`[image: база данных с фото]

Comment: Спасибо, тоже об этом думал все же